# Retrieve AllureXUnit Attribute values after declaring them with Tags

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, allure

I'm using Allure.XUnit for my Unit tests which I use for data validation in files. But since I want to hand out all the files that didnt pass the tests to our testers instead of them needing to manually pick them out by their names out of the allure report. So now I created a method which basicly mirrors the entire "Epic, Feature, Story" Hirarchy from allure in normal windows folders where I then copy the test files to. Since I want to make everything dynamic I tried to retrive the Epic, Feature and Story values for my folder names which I define in the Tags at the beginning of a test function. But I can't access the Feature since the name I gave the Feature in the Tag is stored in an internal string array which is defined from allure xunit.

I tried to make my own attributes and function like so:

```
    public static void CreateFolderStructureForAllure(Usd failedUsd, Type callingType, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
    {
        MethodInfo testMethod = callingType.GetMethod(methodName);

        string epic = null, feature = null, story = null, issue = null, description = null;

        foreach (var attribute in testMethod.GetCustomAttributes())
        {
            if (attribute is MethodImplAttribute) 
                continue;

            PropertyInfo valueProperty = attribute.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
            string attributeValue = valueProperty?.GetValue(attribute)?.ToString();

            switch (attribute)
            {
                case AllureEpicAttribute:
                    epic = attributeValue;
                    break;
                case AllureFeatureAttribute:
                    feature = attributeValue;
                    break;
                case AllureStoryAttribute:
                    story = attributeValue;
                    break;
                case AllureIssueAttribute:
                    issue = attributeValue;
                    break;
                case AllureDescriptionAttribute:
                    description = attributeValue;
                    break;

            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(epic) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(feature) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(story))
        {
            string baseFolderPath = @"C:\tmp";
            string allureFolder = Path.Combine(epic, feature, story);

            string fullFolderPath = Path.Combine(baseFolderPath, allureFolder);

            if (!Directory.Exists(fullFolderPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(fullFolderPath);

            if (File.Exists(failedUsd.Path))
            {
                string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(fullFolderPath, Path.GetFileName(failedUsd.Path));
                File.Copy(failedUsd.Path, destinationFilePath, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class AllureDescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public AllureDescriptionAttribute(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class AllureEpicAttribute : Allure.Xunit.Attributes.AllureFeatureAttribute
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public AllureEpicAttribute(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class AllureFeatureAttribute : Attribute
{
    // Private field to store the features
    private string[] features;

    public AllureFeatureAttribute(params string[] features)
    {
        this.features = features;
    }

    public string Value => string.Join(", ", features);
}

public class AllureStoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public AllureStoryAttribute(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class AllureIssueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public AllureIssueAttribute(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Which technically worked but now the allure functionality is gone since I created my own attributes and its not creating allure-results anymore.
I use the tags like this:

```
 [AllureDescription("This test checks if SEW_X_COORDINATE_TRANSFORMER_VALUE and SEW_Y_COORDINATE_TRANSFORMER_VALUE is NOT longer than 0.5")]
 [AllureEpic("Parameters")]
 [AllureFeature("Action parameters")]
 [AllureStory("XCoordinateTransformerValue YCoordinateTransformerValue")]
 [AllureIssue("USDV-19")]
 [MemberData(nameof(GetUsds))]
```